# connectDragSource for Each Element in map (Drag and Drop: React DnD)

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, react-dnd

How to make each item isDroppable?
As the `map()` function return new Array I decide to pass the `connectDragSource` into the method, but I still get back the *droppable Aray* insted **droppable Each Item** (Shape)

`for..in`, `forEach`, `for..of` also doesn't get back the desire result

Has somebody resolve such issue?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Segment, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { DragSource } from "react-dnd";
import ShapeItem from "./ShapeItem";

class Shapes extends Component {

  displayShapes = (shapes, connectDragSource) =>
    shapes.length > 0 &&
    shapes.map((shape) =>
      connectDragSource(
        <div key={shape.id}>
          <Segment>
            <Icon name={shape.name} size={shape.size} color={shape.color} />
          </Segment>
        </div>
      )
    );

  render() {
    const { shapes, connectDragSource} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {this.displayShapes(shapes, connectDragSource)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const spec = {
  beginDrag(props) {
    return {
      shapeId: props.shapes.id
    };
  }
};

const collect = (connect, monitor) => ({
  connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(spec),
  isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
});

export default DragSource("shape", spec, collect)(Shapes);
```

As for documentation [http://react-dnd.github.io](http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/drag-source-connector) found just only this: *React element as the draggable node. To do that, replace any `element` with `this.props.connectDragSource(element)` inside the render function.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create a separate component to render each item and make it the drag source. You also need to return true from canDrag function in spec.

*Disclaimer: I haven't tested the code below.*

**shapes.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Item from './item.js';

class Shapes extends Component {    
    render() {
        const { shapes } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    shapes.length > 0 && 
                    shapes.map((shape) => <Item key={shape.id} shape={shape} />)
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Shapes;
```

**item.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Segment, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { DragSource } from "react-dnd";

class Item extends Component {    
    render() {
        const { shape, connectDragSource} = this.props;
        return connectDragSource(
            <div>
                 <Segment>
                     <Icon name={shape.name} size={shape.size} color={shape.color} />
                 </Segment>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const spec = {
    beginDrag(props) {
        return {
            shapeId: props.shapes.id
        };
    },
    canDrag(props, monitor) {
        return true;
    },
    endDrag(props, monitor) {
        console.log("You dropped .... into " + monitor.getDropResult());
    }
};

const collect = (connect, monitor) => ({
  connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(spec),
  isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
});

export default DragSource("shape", spec, collect)(Item);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @31113 -- No problem. Glad I was able to help.